# Facebook android sdk how to get the number of likes for a given page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to get the number of likes for a given page with its id.

Here is the [graph api request](https://graph.facebook.com/104249301622?fields=likes) I would like to translate with the facebook-android-sdk.

I cannot figure how to make it. I get errors if I try :

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "likes");
Request request = new Request(session,"104249301622", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {  
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the method to call :

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("id", "104249301622");
params.putString("fields", "likes");
Request request = new Request(session, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        try {
            JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
            numberOfLikes = res.getInt("likes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
});
RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

The request will be translated in the following [graph api request](https://graph.facebook.com/search?id=104249301622&fields=likes).

Comment: In this can you get the total number of likes? @obo

Comment: Yes, it is the total number. You can verify it with using the api call with an id of your choice.

Comment: I have the graph I would like to display the likes from, where would I put this code in my blank Main Activity to display the likes in a simple TextView?

Answer (score 1):

In facebook sdk 3.8

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean("summary", true);


    new Request(
            session,
            id + "/likes",
            b,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                    String s=response.toString();                   
                                 }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

And you will hace the field "total_count" in the Json response.

Comment: can we get both comments/likes count in single request?