# facebook sdk java query getting name from actor_id with graph API or url/http

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

How do I get the name of the actor_id in the same request, and display all the information from the table and the "name"?

```
 SELECT permalink,actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()
```

then I want the name of the actor_id

I know I can use the actor_id results and get the name in a new request

```
 SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=actor_id
```

but, I need to display the permalink and the name together.

How do I get results from

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/user_id?fields=name
```

Can I do a URL/https request to display the name with actor_id results I got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with this request, I got the solution from this [link][Facebook android sdk how to get the number of likes for a given page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169893/facebook-android-sdk-how-to-get-the-number-of-likes-for-a-given-page)

the "id" is from the first query of the actor_id

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("id", id);
    params.putString("fields", "name");

    Request request = new Request(session, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) { try {
  JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                                    final String name = (String) res.get("name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the multiple query using [RequestBatch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/RequestBatch/)-

```
ArrayList<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

// Request-1
String streamQuery = "SELECT permalink,actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()";
Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
args1.putString("q", streamQuery);

Request request1 = new Request(session, "fql", args1, HttpMethod.GET);

request1.setCallback(new com.facebook.Request.Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
         String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
         if (graphObject != null) {
             JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
             try {
               JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
               for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                  Log.d(TAG, "permalink = "+object.get("permalink"));
               }
             } 
             catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
});

requests.add(request1);

// Request-2   
String userQuery = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=actor_id";

Bundle args2=new Bundle();
args2.putString("q", userQuery);

Request request2 = new Request(session, "fql", args2, HttpMethod.GET);

request2.setCallback(new com.facebook.Request.Callback() {
     @Override
     public void onCompleted(Response response) {
         GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
         String s = textViewResults.getText().toString();
         if (graphObject != null) {
             JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
             try {
               JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
               for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                  JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                  Log.d(TAG, "name = "+object.get("name"));
               }
             } 
             catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }
});

requests.add(request2);

// Execute Batch
RequestBatch requestBatch=new RequestBatch(requests);
requestBatch.setTimeout(10000);

List<Response> responses = requestBatch.executeBatchAndWait();
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, but how do I print out the permalink and the name?

Comment: Log the 'responses' you'll find out. This will have both- the prrmalink and name

Comment: how do I define commonLikesQuery?

Comment: My bad. That was `userQuery` actually, I've edited the ans pl check

Comment: That's a request array `Request[]`

Comment: Thanks, also I declared, I hope it is correct:   ArrayList<Request> requests = new ArrayList<Request>();

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, do I have to run OnCompleted to get the responses? how do I do that?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the code. Pls check . PS dont forget to accept the ans if helped :)

Comment: I get error request.setCallback but when I change it to requests I also get errors

Comment: change that to `requestBatch`

Comment: now I get this error --- The method setCallback(new Request.Callback(){}) is undefined for the type RequestBatch

Comment: Remove the old code and use the edited one and let me know the results.

Comment: Remove the one at the starting

Comment: I get this error on the last line ---  Type mismatch: cannot convert from RequestAsyncTask to List<Response>

Comment: now I get error ---   The method executeBatchAndWait() is undefined for the type RequestBatch.  I tried executeAndWait and that did not work as well

Comment: By the way, do I have to put anything in onCompleted like we did before,  String name = (String)graphObject.getProperty("name"); ?

Comment: That depends on what exactly is the response

Comment: What do I Log the 'responses', how to retrieve it?

Comment: Can you see the `responses`?

Comment: no, I can't, I tried with ---      Log.d("RESPONSES", responses.toString());

Comment: SIMPLY LOG `REPONSES` dont convert it to  string and check if the reponse is good?

Comment: It does not let me, I get error ---   The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Response>)

Comment: I got an error from RESPONSES, [{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException}, isFromCache:false}, {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException}, isFromCache:false}]

Comment: It seems that the resposne is null. Can you see the response here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20permalink%2Cactor_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme() ?

Comment: I think it has to do with permissions, I add   args1.putString("request.setPermissions", "status");
but it still did not help

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening. Its difficult for me to understand that without debugging myself.

Comment: I had to change the second query to  ----   String userQuery = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me())";

Comment: I also have seen this problem because of LIMIT

Comment: I changed it to ----     String userQuery = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=me()";
 and I still get null on my name

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with this request: `code                     Bundle params = new Bundle();
                     params.putString("id", id);
                     params.putString("fields", "name");

                     Request request = new Request(nsession, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                      public void onCompleted(Response response) { try {
   JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                               final String nname = (String) res.get("name"); `

Comment: I can't vote yet since I have to have 15 points. As soon as I get them I will vote for you. Thanks again for helping me!