# android facebook java get user name with Graph API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to get name from user id with Graph API, I already have the user id from a SELECT query

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"?fields=name
```

I don't know how to call a http/url query and retrieve the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with this request, I got the solution from this [link][Facebook android sdk how to get the number of likes for a given page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169893/facebook-android-sdk-how-to-get-the-number-of-likes-for-a-given-page)

the "id" is from the first query of the actor_id

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("id", id);
    params.putString("fields", "name");

    Request request = new Request(session, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(Response response) { try {
  JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                                    final String name = (String) res.get("name");
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using the Android SDK, you can make the Graph API calls like this-

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "name");

final String requestId = {actor-id};

Request request = new Request(session, requestId, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
   public void onCompleted(Response response) {
       GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
       FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
       if (graphObject != null) {
          if (graphObject.getProperty("id") != null) {
              String name = (String)graphObject.getProperty("name");
          }
      }
   }
});

Request.executeAndWait(request);
```

Comment: I could have used  SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=id, but the URL query works well on the browser, and I get the results one at a time, and I would like to assign the reseals to a variable.

Comment: The code I have posted does the same. The url query you are saying is nothing but the graph api. This answer does the same, have you tried?

Comment: Try `executeBatchAsync` and to assign it to a var outsie the callback, create a global variable and assign to it `(String)graphObject.getProperty("name")`

Comment: Thanks, great it works, but how do I display the results outside the callback?

Comment: create a global variable and assign to it (String)graphObject.getProperty("name")

Comment: I changed back to executeAndWait, and I still get errors, the problem using executeBatchAsync , is that it does not do a record at a time.

Comment: I set a global var "public String name;" in the beginning of the script before the onCreate, but still in the 
onCompleted the var show that it belongs to onComleted and not to MainActivity

Comment: It seems some basic android problem, try for some time else ill get back

Comment: ok, thanks, I'll try and find out why I get theses errors, I always get them when I try and use executeAndWait

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue with this request: `code                      Bundle params = new Bundle();
                     params.putString("id", id);
                     params.putString("fields", "name");

                     Request request = new Request(nsession, "search", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                      public void onCompleted(Response response) { try {
   JSONObject res = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject().getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0);
                               final String nname = (String) res.get("name");`